# onmouseover(); Not working?

Tags: javascript, html, onmouseover

so I am making a portfolio site over [here](http://www.notelek.com) and for some reason, whenever I try to attach an onmouseover event to any of the icons, nothing happens, I am trying to get the text with my name to fade into the name of the icon you are hovering over, and fade out when you mouse off, is there any way to do this? I have tried about ten 'solutions'

Thanks

Comment: What's your code look like?  And which 10 solutions have you tried, it'd do us no good to suggest stuff you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td onclick="move('url');" onmouseover="alert();" class="tile" id="portfolio"></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed on your site you are loading jQuery so I am going to give you an answer that uses jQuery even though it's not listed on your tags

```
$("#about").mouseover(function(){ //When the mouse enters
    $("span.text").fadeOut("slow",function(){
        //After your name has fadedOut switch the text and fadeIn
        $("span.text").html("About");
        $("span.text").fadeIn("slow");
    });
}).mouseout(function(){ //When the mouse leaves
    $("span.text").fadeOut("slow",function(){
        //After "about" has fadedOut switch with your name and fadeIn
        $("span.text").html("Matthew Foulks");
        $("span.text").fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Hopefully this helps. Ask if you have any questions about this.